# How to get all parameter choices in Revit?

Tags: c#, parameters, revit, revit-api

There is an element's parameter that has like 5 choices (combobox's style). I know how to get the current selected one, but is there a way to retrieve the 4 other choices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are stored in `SimilarObjectTypes` as an `ElementSet`.

```
foreach (Element elem in elemSet)
{
    Parameter param = elem.get_Parameter(paramName);

    if (param != null)
    {
        var similar = elemparam.SimilarObjectTypes;

        foreach (Element choice in similar)
        {
            string ChoiceName = choice.Name;
        }
    }
}
```